# Errors while running the first tutorial (Import SDK Demo)

Tags: dji-sdk

The Logcat (error ) file shows these errors.

2019-03-13 20:29:04.361 7671-7671/com.dji.importSDKDemo E/sdk: install begin
2019-03-13 20:29:04.416 7671-7671/com.dji.importSDKDemo E/sdk: install begin
2019-03-13 20:29:04.857 7671-7694/com.dji.importSDKDemo E/linker: "/data/app/com.dji.importSDKDemo-km6EFSAoVvMZd-4YxdRtug==/lib/x86/libffmpeg.so" has text relocations
2019-03-13 20:29:04.864 7671-7694/com.dji.importSDKDemo E/zygote: No implementation found for byte[] dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(java.lang.String) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX and Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX__Ljava_lang_String_2)
2019-03-13 20:29:04.865 7671-7694/com.dji.importSDKDemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.dji.importSDKDemo, PID: 7671
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for byte[] dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(java.lang.String) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX and Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX__Ljava_lang_String_2)
        at dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(Native Method)
        at com.dji.h.a.a.c.b(Unknown Source:22)
        at dji.midware.e.b(Unknown Source:2)
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.(Unknown Source:2)
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.dji.importSDKDemo.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:123)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I followed the tutorial and the code successfully executed, problem was in the app key . I was using different app key for different project package. Also DJI SDK tutorials run successfully on mobile device than in virtual emulator so it is better to check your application on mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this tutorial to learn how to import DJI Android SDK to your application? https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration